# Can't get 'true white' video output

Tags: transparency, color-management, color

I'm doing a short credits sequence (blend file below), where a few alpha UV materials are overlaid, lit with a single sun lamp.

When I render out the sequence, I can't get a good ol' 8-bit white from settings that I think should get me white. If I export a frame and bring it into Photoshop I get F6F6F6 (246,246,246).

[image: Yep... Not quite white.]

If I increase the sun power I start blasting out the logo colours. Increasing ambient light blasts out shadows. Any tips here?

Blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gklakgma0je92xk/flop3.blend?dl=0

Comment: make your white material shadless if you are using blender internal, or set it to emission if using cycles. You could also increase the intensity of the material.

Comment: This is a *bad* idea if the issue is (unclear in original question) the result is from an encoded video. The correct approach would be to attempt and diagnose whether the encode or the decode or both was mangled. Much to the confusion of many, a codec should deliver a near 1:1 with RGB values, quantization details aside. Not that your solution is necessarily wrong, but that the original question is lacking on context.

Comment: @X-27: Thanks, but I probably won't do the emission idea. I need a shadow to play across the white background, and an emitting object won't receive a very good shadow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your render inside Blender is not pure white.

After rendering clic on the white part of your render in the UV/imge editor, watch the values in the bottom part, R 0.92, G 0.92, B 0.92.

You just need pure texture color and lighting, it's too hazardous to try setting the right orientation and strength of a sun to have perfect texture color. You lose some light during ray casting.

You want two things to compose in post processing:

- the animation of the logo and the text with the correct RGB values (no need of light for that).
- the shadows themselves (need light or tricks that I don't know).

Make a scene without light, and replace the diffuse shaders by emission ones. Now you have the real textures colors, same for the white background. *Bonus: you can set the samples to 10 or 20 it's enough*

Make a second scene with only the sun, the white background and the text for the shadows. Background and text must have diffuse shader this time. On the render layer panel, under passes activate shadow. Render the frames that matter for the Shadows.

Plug the shadow passe in the fac of a color mix node, put the animation of the logo and text in the second image slot of the mix node, the first one is the color of your shadows.

Comment: Thanks Mareck. Interesting idea, but the problem I have with it is that this is a work-around, not a workflow. A diffuse white material lit with a sun lamp on 5 should show a white (or super-white) value. I suspect the problem is related to alpha values. Even though I have three overlapping textures, two of which have transparent values in 8-bit space, might not actually be treated as pure transparent alpha values with Blender. Blender might be converting 8-bit transparency into 16 bit, and that might result in rounding errors for transparent output, darkening lower layers.

Comment: Have a try, delete all except the sun and camera, add a fresh new plan, set a diffuse pure white, hit render.
Exactly the same values, so it's not the alpha chanel.
I continue to think you workflow isn't well suited for what you want.